# performance issue with substr on a very long UTF-8 string

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, substring

I am using `substr` on a very long UTF-8 string (~250,000,000 characters).
The thing is my program almost freeze around the 200,000,000th character.

Does somebody know about this issue? What are my options?

As I am indexing a document using a suffix array, I need:

1. to keep my string in one piece;
2. to access variable length substrings using an index.

As for a MWE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $text = 'あいうえお' x 50000000;

for( my $i = 0 ; $i < length($text) ; $i++ ){
    print "\r$i";
    my $char = substr($text,$i,1);
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: Note that with strings that size, it could be slowing to a crawl because you end up using virtual memory.

Comment: When you say you need an index what you actually mean is that you need to access the string characters randomly?

Comment: @salva yes. however I would say "substrings of variable length" instead of "characters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl has two string storage formats. One that's capable of storing 8-bit characters, and one capable of storing 72-bit characters (practically limited to 32 or 64). Your string necessarily uses the latter format. This wide-character format uses a variable number of bytes per character like UTF-8 does.

Finding the *i*th element of a string in the first format is trivial: Add the offset to the string pointer. With the second format, finding the *i*th character requires scanning the string from the beginning, just like you would have to scan a file from the beginning to find the *n*th line. There is a mechanism that caches information about the string as it's discovered, but it's not perfect.

The problem goes away if you use a fixed number of bytes per character.

```
use utf8;

use Encode qw( encode );

my $text = 'あいうえお' x 50000000;

my $packed = encode('UCS-4le', $text);
for my $i (0..length($packed)/4) {
    print "\r$i";
    my $char = chr(unpack('V', substr($packed, $i*4, 4)));
}

print "\n";
```

Note that the string will use 33% more memory for hiragana characters. Or maybe not, since there's no cache anymore.

Comment: thanx. in your example `unpack` returns a four-bytes integer rigth? How should I proceed to get my character as a string? at the moment I'm doing `chr unpack('V', substr($packed, $i*4, 4));` which is fine; just wondering if there is a way to do it using a pack/unpack pattern...

Comment: oops, yeah, dropped the `chr` by accident. Well, you could use `decode`, but I thought this would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use a regular expression instead of [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

[`Benchmarking`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) these two methods shows that a regex is nearly 100 times faster:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $text = 'あいうえお' x 50_000;

sub mysubstr {
    for( my $i = 0 ; $i < length($text) ; $i++ ){
        my $char = substr($text,$i,1);
    }
}

sub myregex {
    while ($text =~ /(.)/g) {
        my $char = $1;
    }
}

use Benchmark qw(:all) ;

timethese(10, {
    'substr' => \&mysubstr,
    'regex'  => \&myregex,
});
```

Outputs:

```
Benchmark: timing 10 iterations of regex, substr...
     regex:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.18 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.18 CPU) @  4.58/s (n=10)
    substr: 198 wallclock secs (184.66 usr +  0.16 sys = 184.81 CPU) @  0.05/s (n=10)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I need to use an index to access my substring.

Comment: Do you actually need to use an [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/), or are you perhaps suffering from an [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?  Regular expressions can likely handle whatever basic searching you're doing as well, so it is possible it could solve your scalability problem with utf8 strings entirely.

Comment: I am indexing a huge document using a suffix array. So, yes, I need to use an index. My MWE was enough to point my problem however I'll edit my post to make things clear.

Comment: Although this did not help OP, it is an excellent solution for code that can be restructured to use it. I applied it to turn code from quadratic time to linear time in line length. The code originally had linear time, years ago in pre-utf-8 days...

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue listed under Bugs for Perl 5.20.0:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Speed
The most important part is the first paragraph of my quote:

> #### Speed
>
> Some functions are slower when working on UTF-8 encoded strings than on byte encoded strings. All functions that need to hop over characters such as `length()`, `substr()` or `index()`, or matching regular expressions can work much faster when the underlying data are byte-encoded.
>
> In Perl 5.8.0 the slowness was often quite spectacular; in Perl 5.8.1 a caching scheme was introduced which will hopefully make the slowness somewhat less spectacular, at least for some operations. In general, operations with UTF-8 encoded strings are still slower. As an example, the Unicode properties (character classes) like `\p{Nd}` are known to be quite a bit slower (5-20 times) than their simpler counterparts like `\d` (then again, there are hundreds of Unicode characters matching `Nd` compared with the 10 ASCII characters matching `d` ).

The easiest way to avoid it is using byte-strings instead of unicode-strings.

Comment: 1) I don't know why you mention 5.20, since Perl has always used variable-width characters for wide-character strings. 2) None of the OP's characters fits in bytes, so your recommendation makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami: I mentioned 5.20, because I have no idea when they started using variable-width characters, and the quote is from that manual (Did Perl 1 already have them? I doubt that...). If he uses byte-strings, he is responsible for maintaining unicode text semantics where appropriate, but on the upside, he does not get the slowdown caused by the Perl implementation doing so.

Comment: Re "Did Perl 1 already have them?" Perl 1 didn't support characters larger than 8-bit. Larger than 8-bit characters have always been variable-width internally.

Comment: Re "If he uses byte-strings", Again, he can't use byte string. The characters he's using don't fit in 8 bits. If you mean he should be dealing with the UTF-8 encoded form of the text, that would make things much much slower as you would have to do the same work `perl` does, but in Perl instead of in C.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular sample, you can just remove characters from the beginning of the `$text` string as they are processed in order to avoid the linear lookup:

```
use utf8;
use Encode qw( encode );
$| = 1;
my $text = 'あいうえお' x 50000000;

while ($text ne '') {
    print ".";
    my $char = substr($text, 0, 1, '');
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: as said in my post, I don't want to alter the string. thanx anyway.